# What if we don't host our silverlight Application when we first Create it?

Tags: silverlight

As we all know very well..
whenever we create application inside silverlight it is asking us for hosting it 
by dialogue box at given below.

My question is what if i **unchecked** the `check box`[**Host the silverlight application in a new web site**].

Means **what kind of problem** we have to **face later** if **I don't host** our Silverlight Application in any of the option given by dialogue box.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically it is not a problem at all. You can add a website at any time later.

In the project settings of a website there is a `Silverlight` tab. Under that you will find the option to add Silverlight projects to the website. This will setup the links to generate the XAP in ClientBin as well as giving you the option to create test pages for each Silverlight app added. The test pages will give you the sample JS you need to host your Xap later.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to eventually host your application somewhere otherwise it will stay on your local harddrive and hardly reach any clients. So if you have an existing web site you could simply copy-paste the necessary javascript to this site later in order to embed your Silverlight application. In this case you can uncheck this checkbox.